# Exit Sub within nested if statements not working

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to write some VBA code and I have almost everything working pretty well. I just need a little help with a part.

Here is my code:

```
'input if supervisor=fill in supervisor missing
If UserForm1.superbox.Text = "Fill In Supervisor" Then
    If UserForm1.fillbox.Text = "(Fill In Supervisor)" or UserForm1.fillbox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please Enter a Fill In Supervisor.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

After I run it with those conditions, the `Exit Sub` fails.

Comment: Does the message box show up?

Comment: @Minh yes the message box appears. but when UserForm1.superbox.Text = "Fill In Supervisor" , and UserForm1.fillbox.Text = "(Fill In Supervisor)" or UserForm1.fillbox.Text = "" the program should exit sub. but it is not. its just continuing as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around with it for a while and i came up with:

```
        'input if supervisor=fill in supervisor missing
    Dim fis As Boolean
        fis = False

        If UserForm1.superbox.Text = "Fill In Supervisor" Then
            While Not fis
                If UserForm1.fillbox.Text = "(Fill In Supervisor)" Or UserForm1.fillbox.Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox ("Please Enter a Fill In Supervisor.")
                    Exit Sub
                ElseIf UserForm1.fillbox.Text <> "(Fill In Supervisor)" Or UserForm1.fillbox.Text <> "" Then
                    fis = True
                End If
            Wend
    End If
```

The code works great so far!